# mouse and keyboard not working xorg 17.10

Tags: keyboard, xorg, mouse, gdm

So I have follow other similar questions, but because they say switching to xorg solved it for them, I ask again.

I have nvidia drivers because I need them for work they are the latest ones `384.111`.

Im on xorg because I disabled `WaylandEnable=false` and have also used `gnome-shell -r` but without real effect, now for use Ubuntu I need to first start opening all the applications I need, or open them from terminal.

Hiting the windows key doesnt show anything, nor `alt+f1` or `alt+f2` also sometimes the windows mouse clicks on things on other virtual desktop (like instead of sending the commands to the current app to the previous one **or sometimes to the window that is below!!!**), also I need to press `alt+space` to resize or move a window.

How something basic as mouse and keyboard got crashed? and how to solve it without reinstall? (I mean I have already put a lot of effort configuring and downloading things).

What commands can I show you to take a best diagnostic of this?? because "I can use ubuntu" but it is almost unusable right now.

I cant click on:

- gitg
- top right korner for shutdown, so I need to power down the box to shut it down, or write `shutdown now` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `localectl set-x11-keymap us` to set my keyboard layout as US keyboard. I ran given command in tty1 console because my Xorg wasn't launching successfully.

Related man pages:

```
man localectl
man 7 xkeyboard-config
man setxkbmap
```

I am running Arch and that is why I was looking for Arch wiki. `localectl`  must be available in [Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/localectl.1.html).

I got help from [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg).

Comment: This is my first entry on StackOverflow / AskUbuntu. I don't know about markdowns. Sorry for not being able to highlight commands and links like other entries. I hope my answer helps your problem.